# Change the Label Text on Software and Updates App

Tags: updates, software-center, software-sources

I would like to modify the label text on the tabs of Software and Updates Application. Right now it shows "Ubuntu Software":

[image: software and updates screenshot]

I have used KDE Neon and they have managed to get the text label changed to "Neon Software". I have built a custom distro and would like to change the label to something like  "My_Distro_Name Software". Any ideas on how to do it? If the process involves change in source code, please explain what changes to make and where.